# Expo CLI - how to navigate to project?

Tags: expo

I realise this seems like a very simple thing and I expect I'll get downvotes for posting it but I've been at it 3 hours now and I'm literally nowhere.

I have built an app in react native using Expo and now the plan is to create a build. I've installed Expo CLI, but when I log in, how do I tell it which project I want to build? Currently, I type eas project:init and it creates a project using the username of the computer. I'm then unable to navigate out of this project in any way.

I've gone through all the commands on the list in github and none of them does what I need to do.

How do I tell CLI which project I want to work with?

Comment: So... foolish earthling... it helps if you run expo cli from within your project folder... that makes the whole question moot.

Answer (score 1):

You can config it in **eas.json**

For example your project URL like https://expo.dev/accounts/myorgname/projects/appname

```js
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "AppName",
    "slug": "appname", // ✅
    //....
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "YOUR_PROJECT_ID_HERE" // ✅ Go to "Overview" page in Expo.dev for getting your project id
      }
    }
  }
}
```